# Changing Name Format from "Last, First MI." to "First MI. Last" in Java

Tags: java, format

I'm trying take the names that I am given by the program after it retrieves them from unstructured text, and display them in a user specified Format of either "First MI. Last" or "Last, First MI".  Any ideas?  So far it checks to see if a comma is present in the string. if so I want to switch the order of the words in the string and remove the comma, and if there is a middle initial and it doesnt' contain a period after it, I want to add one.

```
if (entity instanceof Entity) {
    // if so, cast it to a variable
    Entity ent = (Entity) entity;

    SName name = ent.getName();
    String nameStr = name.getString();
    String newName = "";

    // Now you have the name to mess with
    // NOW, this is where i need help
    if (choiceStr.equals("First MI. Last")) {
        String formattedName = WordUtils
                .capitalizeFully(nameStr);
        for (int i = 0; i < formattedName.length(); i++) {

            if (formattedName.charAt(i) != ',') {
                newName += formattedName.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    name.setString(newName);
    network.updateConcept(ent);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but where exactly are you stuck? What is your most specific question?

Comment: I suggest striping out all your (irrelevant) code from the question and provide sample input and output - we will provide efficient code to achieve that

Comment: This would be easier if you used `substring` and `indexOf` methods for strings.

Comment: my apologies @Bohemian.  Ok, so imagine that my tool retrieved the name "Smith, John B." I need to take that name and turn it into "John B. Smith", then display it this new name back to the user in place of the old name.

Comment: It's always better to show your attempt first, and then tell us what is wrong with it.

Comment: I know guys, sorry I'm new to all this.  Will remember that on my next post @Hovercraft Full Of Eels.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression and `String.replaceAll`:

```
"Obama, Barack H.".replace("(\\w+), (\\w+) (\\w\\.)", "$2 $3 $1")
```

The result is `Barack H. Obama`.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this (Not that you guys/girls haven't already noticed), but could you take a sec and explain what is going on with ("(\\w+), (\\w+) (\\w\\.)", "$2 $3 $1") ?

Comment: @Ninja-neer: I think I should just point you to [this tutorial](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/). I welcome other readers to post better introductory tutorials if you can find them.

Comment: This [Perl Regular expression tutorial](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm) looks very good. One difference between Perl and Java is that in Java, you have to double-up all of the backslashes that you wouldn't have to double up in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier with `substring`. This assumes that the format is valid (you'll have to check that).

```
//Separate the names
String newName;
String lastName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(","));
String firstName = name.substring(name.indexOf(",")+1);

//Check for a space indicating a middle Name
//Check to see if the middle name already has the period if not add it
if(firstName.trim().contains(" ") && !firstName.contains(".")) {
   firstName += ".";
}

newName = firstName + " " + lastName;

//Set the name to whatever you're using
```

Note this won't work if names are allowed to contain `"," " " or "."`

Comment: This would work if i were just changing one name, but imagine, if you will, that I need to apply this rule to 1000 different names.  I need to run each name through a rule that says "Hey if this string has a comma I need to switch the names around and remove the comma, then replace this new name with the original name".

Comment: @Ninja-neer I would write this as a method, check the names when you receive them, and call the method whenever it's necessary.